# How do I prevent the page from refreshing when closing the modal popup box>

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, popup

So every time I close the popup modal the page will refresh and the popup will appear again so how do I prevent the page from refreshing and have the popup to fadeout once the user click close?

I am not sure if using e.preventDefault(); will do the trick.

Below are my code. Thank you.

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    var a = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (a > 500) {
        $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeIn();
    } else 

    $(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup();

        });
});

function closeSPopup(e){
    $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeTo(0);
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: `e` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter e

```
$(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup(e);
        });
```

To not show on scroll after user clicked close, try this

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    console.log('scrolling - '+$("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed'));
    if (!$("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed')) {
        $(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup(e);
        });

        var a = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (a > 500) {
            $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeIn();
        }
    }
});

function closeSPopup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mc_embed_signup").data('userClosed',true);
    $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeTo("slow", 0, function(){
        //fadeto only set the opacity and doesn't actually hide the div
        //So you need to hide the div after fadeto
        $("#mc_embed_signup").hide();
    }); //check fadeto here http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, thats work perfectly but now every time I scroll the popup re-appear again. Can I make it disappear after user click close?

Comment: try the above example. you need to store a state somewhere (that user has clicked close) and check the state to show popup

Comment: Fade to only set the opacity of the div. So you need to hide it after fadeTo. I thought you would hide it XD. I've updated the code and try whether it works

Comment: You are a life saver, its work pretty well. I simplify the code you gave me because there is no point in having fadeTo so I remove that and just kept the hide which work great. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Now I just need to fix the styling and bring the popup all the way in front, because its behind some of the images and videos. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! And it'd be a great help if you mark correct answer :D

Comment: I marked it and thank you again. I appreciate your help.